# Howto use a database create with a single big model with Entity Framwork with separate Services or Microservices

Tags: entity-framework, microservices

we have a big monolithic project that use EF to manipulates a database.
Now I want to start to create different services or micro-services that use a part of the big-model.
As first step read-only data may be good, but I have to reference all big-model or there is some different way ?

Any help are wellcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with all the microservices sharing the same large DbContext, and maintaining the single shared database.  This allows you to build new services without complicated refactoring of the existing application or database schema.